# Are my website visitor's protected more if i use a vpn while self-hosting website

Tags: vpn, web-hosting

I installed a VPN and started configuring my website to use the VPN addresses, but will that add a stronger layer of security for my website visitor's?

Comment: do your visitors use the VPN address to connect to the server?

Comment: are you aware that the people visiting your site will not get access to the VPN and not get direct VPN access between them and your site?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Are you talking about something like a GRE tunnel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your site uses a VPN, then the connection from your web server to the VPN server is encrypted. The connection between the visitor and the VPN server is not encrypted. The visitors do not get the benefit of the VPN end-to-end to your site.

`Client -- Internet -- VPN Server ++ Web Server`

If you use TLS, then the connection is encrypted end-to-end from client to web server. The VPN will not add any significant protections to the visitor.

Comment: Are you sure that's the final answer? Do you have any references you can refer me to to read this. Thanks.

Comment: There is no need for references. This is how the technology works. The VPN only works between the VPN client and the VPN server. The tunnel does not magically extend past the server offering the service.

Comment: Sounds kind of quirky. I guess your answer must be right.

Comment: A second industry professional here - @schroeder is right.

There are no easy references to give because this is foundational info (so you're right to ask the question if you don't understand!). What about this sounds quirky?